# Why does the ABS say tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' requires quoting?

Tags: bash, tr

There's a code snippet in ABS guide.

```
#!/bin/bash
# uppercase.sh : Changes input to uppercase.

tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'
#  Letter ranges must be quoted
#+ to prevent filename generation from single-letter filenames.

exit 0
```

I don't understand the comment and I am still confused.
Why do I have to quote the letter ranges?
I exec these code in git bash, and everything works fine.
Could anyone show me an example that I'll get an error if I don't quote the letter ranges?

Sorry for my poor English and help...

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide (and the associated FAQ and wiki) are a far more actively maintained resource than the ABS -- the denizens of freenode's #bash channel try hard to keep the Guide up-to-date and accurate, whereas errors in the ABS are rarely fixed if ever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The snippet's comments are wrong (as is much of the ABS; it's a very poor reference and should not be used).

If there were square brackets:

```
tr [A-Z] [a-z]
```

...*then* you'd have a concern about [A-Z] matching files named `A`, `B`, etc. For a more visible demonstration, try this:

```
mkdir -p ~/tmp
cd ~/tmp
touch A B C
echo tr [A-Z] [a-z]
```

...and see what it emits.

---

As a note -- it's possible to get in trouble here even without single-character filenames on your disk if the `nullglob` option is set. To demonstrate that:

```
rm -rf ~/tmp
mkdir -p ~/tmp
cd ~/tmp
shopt -s nullglob
echo tr [A-Z] [a-z]
```

...and you'll see that `tr` is invoked **with no arguments at all**, since `[A-Z]` and `[a-z]` are both interpreted as glob expressions that don't match any files, and `nullglob` tells the shell to simply replace such glob expressions with nothing at all.

---

To be clear -- glob expansion has nothing to do with `tr` specifically; the shell would change an unquoted `[A-Z]` to a list of single-character filenames matching the pattern no matter what program is being run.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.   


[A-Z] matches file A, B, C.   
[a-z] matches file A, B, C.   
so the output of 'echo tr [A-Z] [a-z]' is 'tr A B C A B C'   

It's clear enough.    
But I'm confused with your second code snippet.   
I exec 'shopt -s nullglob' and [a-z]/[A-Z] works as before.   
And, we suppose that [a-z]/[A-Z] does match any file. Then, I guess the output of 'echo tr [A-Z] [a-z]' is 'tr [A-Z] [a-z]' or just 'tr'.
Did you want to say:'echo | tr [A-Z] [a-z]'?   

ps:my bash version is 'GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)'.

Comment: @android_su, which files each pattern matches depends on your locale's collation order -- it's not the same everywhere. Some locales are ordered like `AaBbCc...`, and some are ordered like `ABC...abc...`.

Comment: ...and no, I did not anywhere mean to say `echo | tr`. The goal was to display how tr _would_ be run, if you didn't have the echo, so `echo tr` is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your patient. I think, the output of `echo _something_` is just `_something_`. And so all your examples have nothing to do with `tr`? You said that "you'll see that tr is invoked with no arguments at all". So I thought that maybe you try to say `echo | tr ...`. I am a newer to bash. Sorry for these easy questions.

Comment: I mean, just `echo` is invoked, not `tr`, `tr` is just a string here. right?

Comment: It doens't matter which command is invoked -- the shell performs string-splitting and glob expansion before either command is started, so `echo` gets called with the same arguments `tr` would be, making it adequate to demonstrate the behavior the ABS was warning about. That said -- yes, `tr` is a string here, for demonstrative purposes.